# Sleeping options for ~9 hour stop over at Abu Dhabi International airport

Tags: transit, layovers, sleeping, abu-dhabi, auh

A long trip I will be taking in the future has a stop over of approximately 9 hours at Abu Dhabi International airport, from about midnight through to 9am.  Specifically I am interested in the best sleeping options available, in order to get say 5-6 hours sleep during the stop over.

The options I have found so far include:

1. The "[Airport Hotel](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/airport-facilities/airport-hotels/airport-hotel.aspx)" inside the airport itself.
2. The [Premier Inn](http://global.premierinn.com/gcc/en/hotel/UKPAD2/abu-dhabi-international-airport), which is apparently right across the road from the International airport.
3. The [Sleeping Pods](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/airport-facilities/sleeping-pods.aspx) in Terminal 3 inside of the airport.

There are mixed reviews online for 1. and 2.
3. is still relatively new, so there's not a whole load of reviews online.

For someone who is just looking to get a few hours good sleep between flights, is there any reason to prefer any of the above three options, or, are there other good options available?  The opportunity to have a shower would be nice, though quality sleep is my primary objective.

Comment: What option did you fibnally choose to sleep for a few hours at the airport? I will be in the same situation soon, and was considering the Premier Inn, as the sleeping pods had nearly the same price.But, I would like to know what worked best for you.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/mideast/abudhabi.htm) link has options available from sleeping on the floor in T3 (probably not what you'd consider quality sleep) to lounges to conventional hotels.

> Airport Hotels
>
> - Abu Dhabi Airport Hotel - Location: inside the airport - Terminal 1 Transit Hall, on the right side just after the Departure Immigration Hall. Day rooms are offered from 6am - 6pm.
> - Premier Inn - Location: opposite Terminals 1 and 3. Direct access is available via the Skypark retail corridor.
> - Park Inn by Radisson (6.6km)
> - Yas Viceroy - (6km) 10 minutes from the airport. Transfer service available on request ($) Sleep pods can be found in Terminal 1 (2 pods in the Al Dhabi Lounge) and Terminal 3 (20 pods near gates 35 and 36). Rate: US$ 13 (1 hour) • US$ 25 (2 hours) • US$ 36 (3 hours) • US$ 46 (4 hours).

To find a cheap room, there is a list of hotels near Abu Dhabi Airport on Tripadvisor that can be sorted by price.

Answer (score 4):

I chose the sleeping pods to sleep for 5 hours! They were good but was disgusted that the price you pay doesn't include a blanket and a pillow! £8 for a blanket! We already paid £43 and thought we would get comfort. So if your thinking if the sleeping pod get a blanket and pillow off the plane because they put the air conditioning on so it's cold!!!!!

Comment: This reads more like a rant than an answer, please consider editing

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with in a similar situation in Abu Dhabi last year.  An earlier delayed flight had resulted in me missing my connection.  The airline wouldn't provide a hotel room because it was day time, but my body clock was saying it was the middle of the night and I didn't want to adjust to Gulf time.  The airport is pretty spacious, or seemed so last May, and I had no difficulty in finding a quiet area with plenty of vacant seats in which to sleep.  Whether that satisfies your definition of "quality sleep" will depend how good a sleeper you are, how tired you expect to be, and how unwilling you are to pay or a room or pod.