# 18 hr. layover at Abu Dhabi airport but ineligible for transit visa

Tags: layovers, auh

Traveling for New Delhi to Frankfurt via Abu Dhabi by Eithad, I have a 18 hr. layover at Abu Dhabi airport. As I am ineligible for Transit visa , what are the options at the Abu Dhabi airport for me?

Comment: Why did you punish yourself with such an itinerary?

Comment: Likely useful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/sleeping-options-for-9-hour-stop-over-at-abu-dhabi-international-airport

Comment: let's hope they have comfortable couches in the waiting lounge as you're going to want to take a nap on them...

Comment: Welcome to TSE. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial attempts at research; for example, browsing the [Abu Dhabi Airport website](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/) yields an abundance of information about hotels, shopping, dining, Internet access, spas, and even religious facilities. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help], and return if you have more specific questions that are answerable in our format.